# No encryption crypto object found exception in Apache CXF

Tags: java, wcf, soap, cxf, ws-trust

I am trying to build a Java client that communicates with .NET WCF services that use WS-Trust.

My .net STS uses WS2007Http binding and UserNameToken-based authentication, hosted on http endpoint.

```
var binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
        binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
```

The setting NegotiateServiceCredential is set to false to suppress using SslContextToken that is unsupported by Apache CXF.

My Java client code is following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringBusFactory bf = new SpringBusFactory();
    URL busFile = Main.class.getResource("/cxf.xml");
    Bus bus = bf.createBus(busFile.toString());

    STSClient sts = new STSClient(bus);
    sts.setWsdlLocation("http://localhost:19308/MainTenantManager/SecurityTokenService?singlewsdl");
    sts.setServiceName("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice}SecurityTokenService");
    sts.setEndpointName("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice}WS2007HttpBinding_IWSTrust13Sync");

    sts.setSpnego(true);
    sts.setSecureConv(true);
    sts.setSoap12();

    Properties p = new Properties();       
    p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
    p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", "pass1234!");
    p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", "localhost!");
    p.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", "keystore.jks");

    org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin m = new Merlin(p);

    sts.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_CRYPTO, m);

    sts.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, "admin");
    sts.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.PASSWORD, "qwe");

    sts.requestSecurityToken("http://localhost:19308/MainTenantManager/Service");

}
```

The result is an exception:

```
1437 [main] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/wsdl}SecurityTokenService#{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/wsdl}RequestSecurityToken has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No encryption crypto object found.
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:395)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:124)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:89)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:757)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:635)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:627)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.issueToken(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:69)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:44)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:757)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:635)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:627)
at com.medius.cxf.client.Main.main(Main.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No encryption crypto object found.
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.policyNotAsserted(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.setEncryptionUser(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:1590)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.getEncryptedKeyBuilder(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:1413)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.setupEncryptedKey(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:827)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:296)
... 23 more
```

Which seems to be totally wrong since, the crypto object is set in code. I have tried both configuring the encryption though jaxws:client configuration using .properties file and setting it up in code.

Comment: did you end up solving it ?

Comment: Yes, however I needed to entirely disable SecureConversation on .Net site, then use UserNameToken + Https instead.

Answer (score 1):

What version of CXF are you using? The style of creating a Properties Object, and instantiating a Merlin Object with it + then using it for ENCRYPT_CRYPTO works with both the latest CXF trunk + 2.7.x-fixes code. If you are using an older version of CXF, perhaps try with a more recent version?

Colm.

Comment: It partially helped, in the end I dropped out the WS2007HttpBinding with secure conversation hosted on http for a custom binding with security conversation disabled and hosted it on https to ensure confidentiality. Then I've bumped into problems with parsing binding from wsdl and upgrading CXF finally made it working. I've upgraded it from 2.6.1 to 2.6.14.